# What is the role of Service layer in spring and how do I split my logic in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, architecture

I am trying to write a simple webapp, which takes email id as parameter and generates a token for the user with that id. I think my code is self-explanatory, so I will just paste it here so that I don't have to explain in detail.

This is my controller/servlet code

```
    User user = userManager.getUserByEmailId("xyz@gmail.com");
    if (user == null) {
        //TODO handle this
    }
    if (user.getIssuedTokens() == user.getMaxTokens()) {
        // TODO handle this
    }
    String token = tokenService.createToken();
    user.setToken(token);
    user.setIssuedTokens(user.getIssuedTokens() + 1);
    userManager.updateUser(user);
```

userManager and tokenService are Service layer implementations.

```
@Service("tokenService")
public class TokenizationServiceImpl implements TokenizationService {

    @Autowired
    private TokenDAO tokenDAO;

    @Transactional
    public String createToken() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        tokenDAO.createToken(uuid);
        return uuid;
    }
}


@Service("usermanager")
public class UserInterfaceImpl implements UserInterface {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void createUser() {
        userDAO.createUser();
    }

    public User getUserByEmailId(String emailID) {
        return userDAO.getUserByEmailId(emailID);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userDAO.updateUser(user);

    }

}
```

my spring configuration is like this

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.service" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- dataSource TransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Here are my questions:

1. Does it make sense to inject two services (usermanager and tokenService) into my controller/servlet and then invoke them one after another? Or Should I have written one method in TokenServiceImpl directly, which would make use of usermanager service or UserDAO directly?
2. The transactional attribute did not seem to work for me. When updateUser method failed, a token was created in the database from createToken() method. What am I doing wrong here? Why did not the transaction rollback?
3. How do I in general decide on whether my service should use multiple DAOs or other services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my thoughts about your second question may also answer your first question. Looking to you snippet, I can notice that you are creating two different transactions for `tokenService.createToken()` and `userManager.updateUser(user)` since you are calling them from outside a `@Transaction` method. In order fix this behavior, you gonna need to do something like:

```
public class UserService {

    ...

    @Transactional
    public void assignToken() {
        User user = userManager.getUserByEmailId("xyz@gmail.com");
        if (user == null) {
        //TODO handle this
        }
        if (user.getIssuedTokens() == user.getMaxTokens()) {
        // TODO handle this
        }
        String token = tokenService.createToken();
        user.setToken(token);
        user.setIssuedTokens(user.getIssuedTokens() + 1);
        userManager.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

You can notice that, in order to take into account this new transactional behavior, I created a new business component called `UserService`. Even though I don't really know your application enough to say what is the best approach, I would definitely not let it in your controller. In my opinion, you should isolate this behavior in:

- a new business component (as I did in this example)
- or encapsulate it inside your `UserManager` for instance

Now, is up to you decide whether it's worth coupling `UserService` to `TokenizationService` or creating a new business class for that. Reading the code you provided, it seems to me that `UserService` could have a `TokenizationService` since tokens won't be used in a different context.

Please, let me know your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, all the code in the controller should be in a transactional service. As is your service doesn't do anything other than delegating to methods of the DAO. The service is supposed to contain the business logic, and to demarcate transactions.
2. Each of your services is transactional. So, when calling `createToken()`, a transaction starts and is committed as soon as `createToken()` returns. And when `updateUser()` is called, another transaction is started and commits or rollbacks as soon as the `updateUser()` returns/fails. That's one of the reasons why all the controller code should be in a single transactional service. If that was the case, both calls would be made in a single transaction, and if the second call failed, the whole transaction would be rollbacked, including the token generation.
3. My rule is: if a service just needs to get data from the database, it should use a DAO. If it needs to reuse business logic already defined in another service, then it should delegate to that service.